# How to pass foreach instance as method parameter?

Tags: knockout.js

How to pass foreach instance as method parameter?

In the code below, how do I pass the foreach instance `currentFeature` to `$root.enableDemote(currentFeature)`. Passing it as `$root.enableDemote(currentFeature)` is not working. Any sugegstions?

```html
<tbody data-bind="foreach: { data: features, as: 'currentFeature' }">
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 8px;">
            <button type="button" id="exposureDetailDemoteButton" class="btn btn-default fe-margin" data-bind="click: $root.demoteExposure, enable: $root.enableDemote(currentFeature)" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Demote Feature Exposure"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-backward"></span></button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 2):

$data is the current array entry inside the "foreach" binding:

```
data-bind="click: $root.demoteExposure, enable: $root.enableDemote($data)"
```

Also $index is the iteration index (observable). For more details see [foreach binding documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html).